# Create density plots to compare two variables across many different groups

Tags: r, density-plot

I have two variables with values ranging from 1 to 10. For each variable, there are more than 30k rows, split by many countries (identified by variable "country"). I need to create a combined density plot for these two variables across all these countries.

I know how to do one or other thing. To get a density plot for many different countries, I could use facet_wrap:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=var1)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

To have density plots of two different variables in the same graphic, on the other hand, I could use something like:

```
plot(density(df$var1)) +
lines(density(df$var2))
```

There might be other options like ggjoy, but I couldn't get none of them to work together with facet_wrap or find any other way to have multiple density plots for two variables together.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
This should work for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes) # theme ggplot

# fake data generation var1 and var2 integer between 1 and 10 and random country names from vector country

df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:10,100,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df) <- c("var1", "var2")
country <- c("Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Bahrain", "Morocco", "Namibia")
df$country <- sample(country, 100, replace = TRUE)

# df to long format
df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = var1:var2,
    names_to = "variable",
    values_to = "value"
  )

# plot multilevel density plot
# plot multileve density with facet_warp
p <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=value, group=variable, fill=variable)) +
  geom_density(adjust=1.5, alpha=.4) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  theme_ipsum()
p
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine. Could there be a more automatic way, maybe a function or something like that, since I intend to do that with many variables?